# Unable to kill sar process

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a shell script to run JMeter test. Script generates the Jmeter log out put and creates sar (suppose to create sar file though it does not). Shell script is -

```
runtest() 
{
 export JMETER_HOME=/home/software/apache-jmeter-2.6
 host=$1
 port=$2
 loopcount=$3

 logfile=jmeter$(date -d "today" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").jtl
 sarfile=sar$(date -d "today" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").dat

sar -o $sar_file 3 100000 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
sar_pid=$!;
echo 'sar started with pid' $sar_pid;

for ((start=1; start <= $loopcount; start++ ))
do
 echo 'Iteration' $start;
$JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t ReportWebService.jmx -Jhost=$host -Jport=$port -l $logfile
done
sleep 2
echo 'killing sar process id' $sar_pid
kill -9 $sar_pid;

}

runtest localhost 8087 1
```

When I execute the shell script, I eventually encounter error -

```
sar started with pid 13191
Iteration 1
Created the tree successfully using ReportWebService.jmx
Starting the test @ Tue Apr 17 11:16:24 IST 2012 (1334641584914)
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
Tidying up ...    @ Tue Apr 17 11:16:25 IST 2012 (1334641585129)
... end of run
killing sar process id 13191
./temp.sh: line 22: kill: (13191) - No such process
```

And I don't see any ".dat" file generated for sar data. What is wrong with this shell script?

Comment: At the risk of pointing out the obvious, the `sar` command has evidently terminated by the time you get around to `kill`ing it.  You should be investigating your `sar` command to see if it is working correctly.  Try running the exact command outside the script.  In addition, check your script for typos.  In particular, your question has a typo: you set `sarfile` but use `sar_file`.  Use a consistent variable naming scheme and check your original script to see if that typo exists.

Comment: the error was because of typo in sar_file, I wish I could mark your answer as right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your question: you set `sarfile` but use `sar_file`, which is probably causing your `sar` command to exit with an error.